# Swictching between a MVC and Single page application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, rest, authentication

We have recently developmed our product as SPA using angular.js(1.5) , whereas our old website is a C# MVC project.

Now we want to place a link in old website dashboard (MVC project) such that when user clicks on it he should be automatically logged in and be redirected to  dashboard in SPA website and he would be able to freely navigate to every other modules.

Im not aware of the right way to do it. Can anyone suggest whats usually done, as we have to call a stateless api from a stateful project. ie. i have to use a AJAX call from mvc to pass username and password and i dont know how il be able to handle it at the SPA.

Also i dont want to show the parameters in the url. can anyone suggest with a example or explanation. It would help a lot. 
Thanks

Comment: You could work with cookies, if you don't want to work with URL parameters. If you want to authenticate the user on MVC, you can make a database containing all sessions with a key, you save the key as a cookie and then access the session data again with the backend of the SPA. What authentication method do you use?

Comment: Actually my consern is about authenticating the user in SPA, MVC user is already authenticated as he is given the link only after login.   API team is using WebSecurity.Login methot to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie sharing across domains. It will enable you to log in the user in one site and use the same cookie (and authentication, of course) in the other site. Keep in mind it has limitations, like both websites must have the same second level domain (*.domain.com).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784655(v=cs.20).aspx

Comment: Isnt is a security issue to store the credentials in the cookie and allowing the user access?  any hacker can easily get the password and decrypt it and login to the system ? @Felipe   can u suggest some tricsks to it, or can it be handled from the server.js file in the client end?

Comment: The credentials would not be stored in the cookies. Asp .NET handles the Authentication for you. If you are talking in server.js file, I suspect you are using Node.js, in this case I do not know if you have this option in a Node environment, I only have experience with this in a .NET MVC application.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe ,successfully works in local , but the same thing when released on dev server doesnt work. ie , i cant see the cookie in the browser console of the new application whereas the same is visible in the browser console of older one. Any idea why that happens? Many Thanks